# Prove that $|f'(u_m)(\partial_j u_m-\partial_j u)|\leq(\sup|f'|)|\partial_j u_m-\partial_j u|$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I would like to prove (B) below:
[image]

> $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $D$ denotes the gradient operator. Using the triangle inequality, one can readily obtain
>   $$\int_{\Omega'}|f'(u_m(x))(Du_m)(x)-f'(u(x))(Du)(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_{\Omega'}|f'(u_m(x))|\cdot|(Du_m)(x)-(Du)(x)|\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\Omega'}|f'(u_m(x))-f'(u(x))|\cdot|(Du)(x)|\mathrm{d}x.$$
>   It will be great if we can show that
>   $$|f'(u_m)(\partial_j u_m-\partial_j u)|\leq(\sup|f'|)|\partial_j u_m-\partial_j u|$$
>   for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. But I don't know how to do that. Please help. Thank you.